# Strange <left> behaviour

Tags: init-file, navigation

Usually `<left>` is bound to `'left-char`
I have never edited this in my init file or `<right>` for that matter.
However recently when I'm at the beggining of a line and I type `<left>` it does not go to the last letter of the line above
(or the first letter of the line below if you press `<right>` at the end of the line)
I was wondering if any of you have encountered this issue in the past.
I have a sizeable Init file spanning multiple files and I'm not sure how to tackle this issue.

Thanks in advance for the help.

I have tried

```
(global-unset-key (kbd "<left>") )        
(global-set-key (kbd "<left>") 'left-char)
```

The strange thing is if I call `<M-X left char>` at the beginning of the line
it behaves perfectly normal

Comment: Major modes often modify keymaps (e.g `d` in fundamental-mode inserts it, but the same key in dired-mode marks a file for deletion). You can find out what the key is bound to, using `C-h c`. The name of the function often gives a clue about who did the rebinding.

Comment: What was the command that <left> was bound to, if not left-char?

Comment: strangely enough it was also left-char , no rebinding happened so I assume it was some odd bug with the byte-compiled multiple-cursors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error seems to be in multiple-cursors mode.
It stopped as soon as I removed the following from my .emacs file

```
(package-install 'multiple-cursors)
(require 'multiple-cursors)

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-c") 'mc/edit-lines)


(global-unset-key (kbd "M-<down-mouse-1>"))
(global-set-key (kbd "M-<mouse-1>") 'mc/add-cursor-on-click)
```

Comment: If this resolves your problem, could you please mark your own answer as accepted?